# Getting key-error while looping through files

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm making a loop in some files, checking the extension, and creating some folders based on a Dict depending of the file extension.

Well, something almost go good, but I have this error while creating a new dir.

Anybody has an idea?

---

The error is the following

```
destination = os.path.join(dossier_final, fichiers[f_splited])

KeyError: '"C:/Users/thiba/Desktop/python/formation-developpeur-python/Section30/Exercice 23/01-sources/tri_fichiers_sources\\"'
```

Code:

```
    files = glob.glob(dossier, recursive=True)

    fichiers = {
        "mp3": "Musique",
        "wav": "Musique",
        "mp4": "Videos",
        "mov": "Videos",
        "jpg": "Images",
        "jpeg": "Images",
        "png": "Images",
        "pdf": "Documents",
        "json": "Ok"
    }

    for f in files:
        f_splited = f.split(".")[-1]
        if f_splited in fichiers:
            print("Ok")
        elif f.endswith(f_splited):
            destination = os.path.join(dossier_final, fichiers[f_splited])
            os.makedirs(destination, exist_ok=True)
            if destination:
                shutil.move(f, destination)
```

Comment: You want to use forward slashes instead of backslashes  in `os.path.join`.

Comment: What should happen if there is file in the directory that has an extension that is *not* in `fichiers`, like 'exe'? Your code then checks if `f` ends with `exe` (it does) and then tries to look up `'exe'` in `fichiers` again - this will always fail.

Comment: Thanks Grismar, I add some check if f is in fichiers, and it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suffix `f_splited` would have the value `''` for that folder.

Since this is not a valid file format type in `fichiers` you will receive the key error. You should filter out folders from your list produced by `glob`.

Answer (score 1):

If your loop makes it to `destination = os.path.join(dossier_final, fichiers[f_splited])`, that means that `f_splited` is not in `fichiers`. So trying to access `fichiers[f_splited]` is a key error - there is no such thing as `fichiers[f_splited]`.